# Comment Box's Post To Wall - Meta Tags Not beIng Recognized

Tags: facebook, metadata, meta-tags, comments

I've been creating some basic contests for clients the past few months and all was going well until a few weeks ago when the developer's edit applications page was redone. Now all our past comment boxes are coming up with a warning message stating "Warning: http://apps.facebook.com/OURAPPNAME/ is unreachable."

When creating new apps we don't run into the above problem but the Post To Wall feature is now not recognizing the Meta Tags and states "NAME commented on "URL"" Instead of "NAME commented on TITLE" with an image + description.

Is anyone else running into these issues? I would be happy to post some code if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see what we see when scraping your site. You can paste in a URL and see if the OG tags are being properly picked up. If there are any errors or anything's missing, it will let you know.

Comment: All info was pulled correctly in the debugger but is not being pulled when the comment box is commented on. Photo can be seen here, I had to blur out some info for client privacy.

http://360pr-design.com/CommentWallPost.png
http://360pr-design.com/InfoScreen.png

Comment: Okay, it looks like if you're using a canvas URL (e.g. ...apps.facebook.com/...) as the href of the Comments Plugin we don't scrape the tags on that specific page but rather the base canvas URL. Could you test to see if that's the issue on your end and if so [file a bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net) so we can look into it? Thanks.

Comment: Just tested the comment box again this morning and it's working! Thanks for responding/troubleshooting with me though :)